# Resource Adapter Binding Solace, WMQ, JBOSS EAP 6.4

Tags: jboss6.x, solace, resource-adapter

I am trying to connect to WMQ and Solace messaging framework to consume messages from both
I have multiple listeners for WMQ but while trying to associate/bind another listener to solace adapter, application does not start

As only last listener is getting binded to solace

Reference file

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss:ejb-jar xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:c="urn:clustering:1.0" xmlns:r="urn:resource-adapter-binding"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-ejb3-2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1" impl-version="2.0">
    <enterprise-beans>

        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>CoreMessageEventListener</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.slohiya.ListenerA</ejb-class>
            <activation-config>
                <activation-config-property>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                </activation-config-property>
            </activation-config>
        </message-driven>
        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>ListenerB</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.slohiya.ListenerB</ejb-class>
            <activation-config>
                <activation-config-property>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                </activation-config-property>
            </activation-config>
        </message-driven>


        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>ListenerX</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.slohiya.ListenerX</ejb-class>

            <activation-config>
                <activation-config-property>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                </activation-config-property>
            </activation-config>

        </message-driven>

        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>ListenerY</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.slohiya.ListenerY</ejb-class>

            <activation-config>
                <activation-config-property>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                </activation-config-property>
            </activation-config>
        <message-driven>

    </enterprise-beans>  

    <assembly-descriptor>
        <r:resource-adapter-binding>
            <ejb-name>ListenerA</ejb-name>
            <r:resource-adapter-name>wmq.jmsra.rar</r:resource-adapter-name>
        </r:resource-adapter-binding>
    </assembly-descriptor>
    <assembly-descriptor>
        <r:resource-adapter-binding>
            <ejb-name>ListenerB</ejb-name>
            <r:resource-adapter-name>wmq.jmsra.rar</r:resource-adapter-name>
        </r:resource-adapter-binding>
    </assembly-descriptor>

    <assembly-descriptor>
        <r:resource-adapter-binding>
            <ejb-name>ListenerX</ejb-name>
            <r:resource-adapter-name>com.solacesystems.ra</r:resource-adapter-name>
        </r:resource-adapter-binding>
    </assembly-descriptor>

    <assembly-descriptor>
        <r:resource-adapter-binding>
            <ejb-name>ListenerY</ejb-name>
            <r:resource-adapter-name>com.solacesystems.ra</r:resource-adapter-name>
        </r:resource-adapter-binding>
    </assembly-descriptor>

</jboss:ejb-jar>
```

So in this case JBOSS is trying to associate ListenerX to wmq.jmra.rar and fails.

In standalone.xml default adapter is wmq but stil, it should be possible to override it in jboss-ejb3.xml and it works fine if I use only one listener for solace adapter.

```
<mdb>
                <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="wmq.jmsra.rar"/>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </mdb>
```

Problem occurs only when I am trying to use multiple listeners with solace as resource adapter.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've no issue with "@ResourceAdapter(value="com.solacesystems.ra")" annotation inside the MDB, can you try that? Also, what's your ejb-jar.xml and are there any annotations inside the MDB source?

Comment: Thanks for response Russel. I am trying that and will update on this forum

Comment: This does not work with annotations as well, I had to create separate project for a listener for solace and configure adapter in jboss-ejb3.xml file of that project, however, within this project also, I am not able to associate/bind solace adapter for 2 solace listeners listening to separate queues.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this to work using the assembly-descriptor now. 
I believe that the problem is that you have multiple `<assembly-descriptor>` sections that result in a strange behavior from JBoss.

Here is a sample jboss-ejb3.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="urn:clustering:1.0"
    xmlns:r="urn:resource-adapter-binding"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-ejb3-2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1" impl-version="2.0">

    <enterprise-beans>
        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>MDB1</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.test.MDB1</ejb-class>
            <activation-config>
                ...
            </activation-config>
        </message-driven>
        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>MDB2</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.test.MDB2</ejb-class>

            <activation-config>
                ...
            </activation-config>
        </message-driven>
    </enterprise-beans>

    <assembly-descriptor>
        <r:resource-adapter-binding>
            <ejb-name>MDB1</ejb-name>
            <r:resource-adapter-name>com.solacesystems.ra</r:resource-adapter-name>
        </r:resource-adapter-binding>

        <r:resource-adapter-binding>
            <ejb-name>MDB2</ejb-name>
            <r:resource-adapter-name>com.solacesystems.ra</r:resource-adapter-name>
        </r:resource-adapter-binding>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</jboss>
```